# How to Update a textbox with a value from another textbox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two `textboxes` named `totalAmount` and `expenseAmount` and another a `div` called `currentAmount` in asp.net page(using C#).
My requirement is I have to update `totalAmount=expenseAmount+currentAmount` whenever `expenseAmount` value changes.I have to achieve this without page refresh and value should be persist even after page refresh.

Comment: write your code for summation in Text Changed event of that text box. auto postback property must be true. and use updatepanel if you dont want to refresh the page

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is I am using a custom tool.Here I have only limited controls to use. So I cant use updatePanel in it.

Comment: you can use javascrpt for textchange  http://forums.asp.net/t/1346989.aspx?calling+javascript+function+on+TextBox+Change+Event

Comment: But I will lost the value after page refresh. I don't want to lost after page refresh.

Comment: What do you mean by "value should be persist even after page refresh"? Is it that you what the value to persist after pressing F5 or click a button to cause a postback?

Answer (score 2):

if your code permit to use JQuery, you can do it easily without page refresh.

please write code under document ready.

```
<script>
    var calculatetotalamount = function () {
        var eamount = parseFloat($("#expenseAmount").val())
        var camount = parseFloat($("#currentAmount").val())
        $("#totalAmount").val(eamount + camount);
    }
    $(function () {

        calculatetotalamount();
        $("#currentAmount").on("change", function () {
            calculatetotalamount();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It is done in client side right? But value should not persist after page refresh. I want the value even after page refresh.

Comment: both expenseamount and currentamount are user inputed?

if yes , you have use memory to store data like session/cookie.

if not then after page refresh totalamount won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xyz() {
        $("#totalAmount")[0].value = parseFloat($("#expenseAmount").val()) + parseFloat($("#currentAmount").val());
    }
</script>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="currentAmount"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="currentAmount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="expenseAmount"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="expenseAmount" runat="server" onchange="xyz();" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="totalAmount"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="totalAmount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```